# What is directory listing vulnerability?

Tags: security, web-applications, directory, directory-listing

What is directory listing? How is it a vulnerability in terms of web application security?

Answer (score 3):

Directory listing, as it is named, allow a user to view all the files (including source files) under a directory served by the web site. If an adversary is able to view all the files (including the source files), one can forge attacks that potentially can by-pass the security checks. This basically turns a black box into a white box from the adversary's point of view, which reduces the complexity of attack.